# How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?

Tags: xorg, lightdm, login-screen, unity-greeter

> ### Note:
>
> This is an attempt to create a canonical question that covers all
> instances of "low-graphics mode" error that occurs to a user,
> including but ***not* limited** to installation of wrong drivers,
> incorrect or invalid lightdm greeters, low disk space, incorrect
> installation of graphics card like ATI and Nvidia, incorrect
> configuration of xorg.conf file while setting up multiple monitors
> among others.
>
> If you are experiencing the "low-graphics mode" error when trying to
> login but none of the following answers work for you, please do ask a
> new question and then update the answers of this canonical question as
> and when your new question gets answered.

---

When I try to boot into my computer, I am getting this error:

> **The system is running in low-graphics mode**
>
> Your screen, graphics cards, and input device settings could not be
> detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

[image: fail-safe X mode]

How do I fix the failsafe X mode and login into my computer?

---

Answer index:

- [The greeter is invalid](https://askubuntu.com/a/141607/25798)

Comment: What happens when the message you see here is almost impossible to read? And I can forget about being able to see the terminal in the Ctrl-Alt-F1 trick.

Comment: I tried to add to the master question but apparently am too much of a newb to be useful.

Comment: ok i tried everything on this page, but the fix for me was to make some more room.

"df -h" showed sda1 as 100%
so then i run "du / | sort -g" and found trash was like 30gig... 80% of harddrive, so i did "rm -fr ~/user/.blah/trash" and followed up with another df -h showing 14%, so a final reboot and i was back in.

Comment: @Braiam I realize this is old, but... this question is protected. It's pretty obviously visible.

Comment: I had the same problem but i fixed it from this link http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/07/ubuntu-1404-lenovo-g510.html

Comment: I had this problem after doing [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151467/how-can-i-get-a-command-to-run-before-login-ie-while-booting-or-just-after/151479#151479)

Comment: I am a newb to Linux but my two last days trying a lot of suggestions to figure out what is the reason behind the error . may I ask you please if setting bad permissions to /var/' can be a reason also? the last operations I was doing on my ubuntu 16.04 desktop are blinded `chmod`s and `chown`s to that directory. Can it be true? thanks

Comment: This happened on a VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest.  The guest uses the host's graphics via interfaces contained in Guest Additions. To fix, simply reinstall Guest Additions.

Answer (score 151):

Will try to answer the ones I can:

Assuming the answer by Jokerdino was already checked: [The greeter is invalid](https://askubuntu.com/a/141607/7035)

### Issues with Nvidia or AMD/ATI graphics

This happens when a driver has a problem installing correctly (Most cases). For this do the following:

1. Boot PC leaving <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> pressed to make the GRUB Menu show.

   [image: Grub menu]
2. Select **Recovery Mode** which will continue booting correctly until the Recovery Menu appeares.
3. Select from the recovery menu **failsafeX**.

   [image: recovery menu, yes it's german please replace :( wasn't able to get it in english by changing system language and doing update-grub]
4. In some cases failsafeX will load fine (You lucky dog), for others (Me) it will give  an error along the lines of "The system is running in low-graphics mode" and will stay there forever. When this happens, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to the terminal. Type in your Username and Password.

   [image: low graphics mode error message]
5. Reinstall the drivers depending on your case:

   - **Nvidia**

     `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` - More stable/tested version
     `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates` - More up-to-date version

     For other cases see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86977/how-to-correctly-enable-desktop-cube-in-unity-3d?lq=1) for details and follow the links there to help you along the way.
   - **AMD/ATI**

     The simple way is to `sudo apt-get install fglrx`. If this does not work keep reading.

     Go to [AMDs support site](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86) and download the driver you need. (If you have a newer card, you may want to download be the latest beta driver instead of the stable one. You would need to compare release dates and read through release notes to find out which driver version supports which chips.) Put the downloaded driver in some folder and rename it to "amd-gpu.run" to simplify name. Go to the folder where you downloaded the file and type `chmod +x amd-gpu.run` to give it Executable Permission. Now just simply run `./sh amd-gpu.run` and follow the onscreen steps.

     After rebooting all problems should be solved. If you test 'Additional Drivers' with a problem like this it will finish downloading the package but then it will give an error. It also gives the same error if you use 'Software Center' and 'Synaptic'. The only way was to go to the `failsafeX` option and do the workaround about changing to the `tty1` terminal and doing it via command line.

Note that if the problem occured after installing an unsupported driver from the amd site then you may have to first delete the driver you had installed. For this, run in the tty session (i.e) in the terminal screen you get after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> :

```
sudo aticonfig --uninstall
```

(If this command didnt work then check [this site](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Catalyst-Linux-Installer-Notes.aspx) . Look under the "Uninstalling the AMD Catalyst™ Proprietary Driver" heading.) After doing this, you may reboot with the command :

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Now you must get back access to the Unity desktop(Of course with the AMD driver uninstalled). Then you can get to [this site](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) which clearly helps in choosing the right AMD driver for your System specifications. Also read the release notes for the latest driver for your graphic card(Especially check if your system satisfies all the system requirements). Then after downloading your driver installer(the .zip file) get to [this site](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Catalyst-Linux-Installer-Notes.aspx) and follow the instructions to install your driver. Your driver must be installed and it should work successfully.

I also need to add that **I do not recommend downloading the Drivers from the Nvidia** site since they:

```
 * Might create additional problems with Ubuntu
 * Are not updated automatically
 * Are not tested thoroughly in Ubuntu
```

Always use the `nvidia-current` package or the `nvidia-current-updates` one. These are tested and approved already for the Ubuntu version you are using and will give less errors and incompatibility bugs.

### Issues with Intel graphics

For Intel it is recommended to do the following after doing all the steps mentioned above but before installing anything (When you are in the Terminal). You can choose Xorg-Edgers which is a PPA that brings many improvements, latest video drivers and more:

Warning: This PPA is very unstable for some things. So do it with that in mind.
 `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y`

After that `sudo apt-get update` and you should receive several updates. X-Swat currently does not have Intel drivers in the latest versions of Ubuntu.

---

### Update log

**UPDATE 1:** Added this extensive answer to solve many of the problems that might end with the error mentioned here: [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/which-driver-should-i-install-when-using-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card/61433#61433)

**UPDATE 2:** AMD is no longer releasing (stable) graphics drivers on a monthly basis and not all graphics chips are supported by their Linux drivers upon product release. At the time of this update the latest stable driver is *almost 5 months older* than the latest beta driver. You should look at the release notes to check if there is a driver that supports your graphics chip and the software versions you are using (X.org xserver or Mir).

---

Like always please test and give feedback so I can enhance my answer since others will be also reading it. The better it is, the more people it will help.

Comment: After trying all the other solutions, that's the one that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This worked! Running in VirtualBox on Mac. Did: 
sudo apt-get install fglrx;
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates -y;
sudo apt-get update;

Also reinstalled ubuntu-desktop before this, not sure if that had an effect

Comment: This worked great for my virtualbox machine on my windows laptop. However I didn't have to enter Recovery Mode. I was able to just boot, hit CTRL - ALT - F1 when I see the screen, then run the command for nvidia and sudo reboot. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Same as b1ackjosh and worked for me. Thanks...!!!

Comment: It didnt worked for me. If I boot in legacy mode and change and select nomodeset then every thing works fine. But when i boot in efi mode it stucks.

Comment: @flamingpenguin can you add the model yo had and Ubuntu version.

Comment: Upgrading from 12.04 to 13.10 with Radeon 3000: I had to remove and purge the fglrx, then remove "nomodeset" from my /etc/default/grub, then update-grub. To remove fglrx {sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*} {sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core} {sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg}. Also had to add "radeon.audio=1" to /etc/default/grub

Comment: Nothing happens in my case here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/465337/ati-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-14-04?noredirect=1#comment615368_465337. The problem is not going by anyway

Comment: @Diffy A couple of Q: Did you purge all ATI related packages. Cleaned the /var/cache/apt/archive folder of DEB packages, removed any custom conf file and rebooted to start from scratch?

Comment: I followed this method https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: This worked wonderfully on a Lenovo ultrabook using AMD. I have one small suggestion though - please include a section on how to enable wireless internet from the CLI. I originally opted to do an offline install (slow internet speed at the office) and of course couldn't **apt-get** anything. Googling for CLI wifi connections turned up pages far too complex for someone new to Linux like me. Ultimately I had to drop the partition and start from scratch with an online install.

Comment: ctrl+alt+f1 doesn't give me a terminal

Comment: @schwiz I suggest to create a question about it. It could be missing configuration file, wrong configuration setup and more.

Comment: @AndrewHeath I actually did: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16584/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-to-a-network-manually-in-terminal/16588#16588

Comment: @Luis thanks for the suggestion, is there anything else you suggest I add, I'm not getting any traffic, upvotes, or suggestions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/516543/stuck-in-low-graphics-mode-normal-method-not-working

Comment: @schwiz check out your question again and try my advice. I got that problem one time on 11.10 or 12.04.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado `nvidia-current` can install the wrong driver. It happened to me. You can install bumblebee for nvidia graphic cards. It will installed the correct driver automatically. After `ctrl + alt + f1`, you can use the following commands: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable` 
`sudo apt-get update` 
`sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic` 
**NOTE:** Follow [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) for other than 14.04 LTS.

Comment: @user281989 Excellent feedback and true. It can give the wrong driver. The same issues happens if we install bumblebee. on both cases it depends on the Ubuntu version, arch and nvidia driver. Thank you for your feedback. +1

Comment: @LuisAlvarado You want believe or not, I love you. You saved my life.

Comment: I had kept an additional kernel having one step lower version. When the screen http://i.stack.imgur.com/5kllk.png showed up, I selected the lower kernel and could login in normally. Though I still did see some system errors. I corrected them later.

Comment: you could erase Ubuntu and reinstall it, it worked for me

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Problem encountered while **upgrading to 16.04**. In my case booting in recovery mode was [inconclusive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819061/) while, through regular booting, I eventually found my way to the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819190/).

Comment: Thank you! After fail safe mode showed the low graphics more error ctrl+alt+f1 booted me up normally :)

Comment: I did this procedure and now I have my computer which does not recognize anymore any USB device. The mouse/keyboard are gone. !! Incredible. I have an intel graphic card and I am not sure now how I am supposed to go back

Comment: It was my fault, of course, I always forget that on this laptop I don't have a NVIDIA graphic card. Therefore, I removed all the installed nvidia drivers. Then I removed the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file. I rebooted and it worked. I had to adjust the resolution of the monitor. But now I have DP and VGA perfectly working. I think my problem was due to the installed NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: @minidiable Thank you for letting us know friend. Glad you solved it.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado it worked once, but now I have again the problem that the DP monitor is not detected at all.

Comment: This is how I finally solved my problem: super clean and easy. 

https://askubuntu.com/a/958031/335044

Comment: I just ran into this problem and I can't boot to grub holding Shift(I think boot timeout is set to 0), has anyone resolved this already? Do I have to use a live CD to fix this problem? I have no idea what to do

Comment: I feel stupid. Just after I posted this comment I ran `ctrl+alt+f1, logged in and fixed the problem!

Comment: While the Answer helped until 4th Point, I faced 2 problems *1.* How do I enable networking service and *2.* Pressing [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [F1] dropped me into Terminal but didn't get a prompt to enter credentials. However @jokerdino 's answer reminded me that I have 2nd OS and it helped.

Answer (score 78):

I solved this problem by reinstalling ubuntu-desktop.

When the message that "your system is running in low-graphics mode" appears, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then login with your credentials.

And then, run the following commands:

- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
- `sudo reboot`

Comment: when i give this command!i got memory is full no more space available!

Comment: This may help when the problem is to do with the desktop, but usually for me this type of problem comes from a combination of the graphics drivers and a kernel upgrade. In this case the other answers here are more appropriate, with particular reference to @Luis.

Comment: @Thiyagu your problem is that you don't have more space in the hard drive.

Comment: I don't quite get how, but this is what solved my problem. thank you for sharing it!

Comment: For me it started with the network-manager-gnome being on version 0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2.4, which meant that 'Edit Connections...' was greyed out. When I forced 0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2 in Synaptic Package Manager, it decided for 'ubuntu-desktop' and 'unity-greeter' to be removed. I hadn't realized at first, I was just happy to have the 'Edit Connections...' option back in the downgraded applet. Well, until the next restart where nothing seemed to help. After following this advice, I can use my system again, but of course 'Edit Connections...' is greyed out again...

Comment: My issue not solved after reinstalling desktop, what i can do more

Comment: Thank you so very much for this! I wasn't able to mount the drive in write mode using regular recovery mode and also there was no network connection, I suspect it has something to do with my harddrive being encrypted. Ctrl+Alt+F1 allows you to actually log in, so from there on I had full access to the computer (even my own bash aliases) and then reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` solved the problem right away. I'm running 14.04, and I found myself in this jam after doing dist-upgrade with `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`, purging the PPA and then downgrading.

Comment: This is a really important early step because it *should* reset everything to sane defaults.  The fact that it occasionally doesn't is a bug IMHO.

Comment: I also saved myself using this. Thanx a ton!!!

Comment: this worked. First I reinstalled my nvidia drivers then used this. Thanks a tom

Comment: worked really well for my lenovo y510p with nvidia graphic card on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: didn't work for me.

Comment: I had this issue with Ubuntu 16.04 with VMWare and this solution perfectly worked for me!! thank you

Comment: It did not worked for me on Ubuntu 16 (Intel graphics only).

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 18.04. The problem arose after upgrading from 16.04

Comment: Will reinstalling ubuntu desktop wipe my machine?

Answer (score 52):

#### The greeter is invalid

This is a bug in LightDM and a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/971891) has already been filed.

The reason why you end up with this failsafe X is because the pantheon-greeter you installed along with the elementary desktop is now not available and LightDM is not able to identify an alternative greeter.

As a workaround, you can edit the LightDM conf file and correct the error.

Run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and change the line

```
greeter-session=pantheon-greeter
```

to

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

and save it.

After changing the file, reboot and you will now be greeted with Unity greeter.

Comment: That workaround doesn't works for me. I'm speaking around three hundreds clients that doesn't works. But the bug is not continous, it's appears randomly.

Comment: This doesn't help in my case. I already have the unity-greeter in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Comment: @Sauli but are you sure that the unity-greeter package is installed on your machine? In my case, after an upgrade to 13.10, `lightdm.conf` indeed mentioned `unity-greeter`, although I only had `lightdm-gtk-greeter` installed. You might want to check which greeter is installed on your machine (e.g. through `synaptic`).

Comment: @Virgile, yes, the unity-greeter version is 13.10.3-0ubuntu1. I don't have lightdm-gtk-greeter installed. At the end, after trying many proposals at this page, I solved the problem by reinstalling 13.10 from a USB drive. I made the reinstallation on top of the existing, non-working 13.10.

Comment: It's prefect, It's right answer.

Comment: I ran into this problem after following the instructions from [the easylinuxtipsproject page on converting from ubuntu to xubuntu](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative). In this case, the following changes needed to be made in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`: change `user-session` from `ubuntu` to `xubuntu` and change `greeter-session` from `unity-greeter` to `lightdm-gtk-greeter`

Comment: Worked for me. Just see, what greeter you have actually installed by typing

`sudo apt-get search greeter`

Comment: Not sure what happened, but after some updates, I discovered my greeter was `unity-greeter1`; yes, with a `1` appended to the end. Have no clue how this happened... This post saved my already balding head ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have unity-greeter installed. Installing it solved my problem. I was installing and removing video drivers but nothing working. Terrible error message!

Comment: Apparently I created this problem for myself by creating the file lightdm.conf and adding the line "allow-guest=false" to try to remove the guest account in Ubuntu. Deleting lightdm.conf fixed the problem for me.

Comment: That file doesn't exist on my Ubuntu 16.10 - only /etc/init/lightdm.conf which doesn't contain the string "greeter".

Comment: This made the trick after reinstalling nvidia drivers

Comment: that file does not exist on ubuntu 16. when I created this file, it didnt work either

Comment: This answer reminded me I have a Second OS and that too Elementary OS. This was the exact solution I required.

Answer (score 38):

**You have too many files on your computer, and have exhausted disk space**

Try moving personal files off the computer onto a USB drive.

---

*To check whether this is the issue:*

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Type `df -h`
3. If you see that there is no space available on the root (`/`) then you need to free some space.

*To free space you can:*

1. `sudo apt-get autoclean`
2. Look for large directories with `sudo du -sc /*/* |sort -g` and delete unwanted content,
3. Clean your home directory using a combination of

   ```
   cd ~   
   du -sc * |sort -g
   rm myLargeFile
   ```

When this is done, restart: `shutdown -r now`

Comment: It is a valid reason. If you exhaust disk space. Ubuntu will run in low graphics mode. I tested this in virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks! This did the job for me. Initially I did not think of checking the remaining space on the SSD.

Comment: Happens also in 13.04. This is definitely a usability bug since there is no message anywhere that can give a clue about the disk space issue.

Comment: My issue now is that in recovery mode it is mounting the disk in read only mode so I'm unable to delete any files to resolve the issue. Any idea how to resolve this?.

Comment: I guess this may have been related to my case. I was running out of space on /root. But freeing space with clean or autoclean didn't solve the wholw problem nor did repartitioning and allocating more space.

Comment: This was my issue, but it was not due to *actual disk use*, but rather this 2006 bug (yes. It's now 2015.) where .xsession-errors grows to an insane size:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/60448

Comment: Thanks,It's just the awesome answer for those who are running out of disk memory, This solved my low graphic mode problem, THANKS A TON, God bless U :)

Comment: for once i thought myLargeFile is a file name

Answer (score 25):

When this happens there is often an error message indicating why it failed to start X.

Look in your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.  The error (if there is one) will be at the tail end of the file.  Another good place to look is the log files in `/var/log/gdm/*` (or `/var/log/lightdm/*` in oneiric and later).

Did you happen to manually install fglrx prior to noticing the problem?  If it was not uninstalled properly it can cause weird random issues.  Directions for purging fglrx are available at [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver).

Is your video card an AGP model?  If so, a common issue with ati agp cards is having an incorrect AGPMode.  Sometimes you can adjust this setting in your BIOS (which perhaps windows screwed with?)  There is also a setting in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` for adjusting it in X.

Answer (score 21):

It is not related to Nvidia drivers. Because by default Ubuntu uses non-Nvidia drivers even though you might have Nvidia GPUs. I have an Nvidia GPU too.

My Ubuntu used to boot fine until something happened which caused the same issue. After reading posts, reading logs and little bit trial and error, turns out the problem is related to lightdm GUI server.

I don't know solution to the problem but there is a quick work around in 3 steps. This will save you from reinstalling Ubuntu.

1. When the error shows up, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. This will open the command line interface. Login as root.
2. Remove a particular X11 config file. This file is not really required.

   ```
   rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe
   ```

   Somehow, the existence of the above X11 configuration file causes the OS to throw that error.
3. Restart lightdm GUI server.

   ```
   service lightdm restart
   ```

This will restart the lightdm GUI server and voila your desktop is back!

Comment: I did exactly this and it worked for me, not sure if this is worth mentioning(using a nvidia gtx860m)

Comment: This was the answer that ultimately solved it for me (along with doing `sudo apt-get upgrade` etc.). Using NVIDIA GeForce 7025.

Comment: This worked for me. Shocking.

Comment: This works for me but when I restart the system the file is created again and system goes into low graphics mode. Is there a work around this? How can I stop from creating this file?

Comment: This seems to have worked, and seems much less intrusive than the reinstall of the desktop.

Answer (score 17):

Let's assume, arrogantly, that it is a problem with your X display manager.

Enter the terminal (you can use a [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) if you cannot use a graphical terminal window), the one you said that you have access to, and enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

. . . and choose gdm.

Then type:

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

(Or `... start` instead of `restart`.)

According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1070150 this is a way to workaround a bug with lightdm.

Before typing that, you may need to first stop the other display manager that is running. This is usually LightDM:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

If you have trouble getting GDM to start, and this is an installed system rather than a live environment, then you can just reboot and it will start automatically because you configured it as the default display manager. (You should be able to shut down and restart normally. Otherwise, one way to reboot if the GUI is not working properly is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> while on a [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console).)

Comment: This did work for me, but could you please explain why it would work?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not an expert. I just posted a solution I found for myself.

Comment: This didn't work for me and got me further off, now I don't even get the low graphics error but just a black screen.

Comment: Don't do this solution if you already have lightdm. My system got screwed up as I was running two such services. Luckily I got out of the mess with switching back to lightdm by running this command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

Answer (score 13):

**Only for ATI graphics cards**

When the message that "your system is running in low-graphics mode" appears:
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to see the terminal one. Then login with your credentials, and then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx    
sudo reboot
```

The same can be done from the recovery mode (after enabling networking), if your Ubuntu completly refuses to enter anything but recovery mode.

Answer (score 13):

Follow these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm
sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
```

(I ran this command above, but was told by the system to use   # sudo apt-get autoremove  instead, after the  #sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm    command.)

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

select GDM when prompted

```
sudo reboot
```

That fixed it for me :)

It took very long to start after the reboot, 10+ mins. But I got in eventually.

Answer (score 12):

I have recently received a similar issue with myPangolin Performance laptop. The folks at System 76 told me to do the following:

Click Okay and then select the option to get a terminal.  (alternatively you can press ctr+alt+f1 to bring up another tty)

```
sudo chown lightdm:lightdm -R /var/lib/lightdm
sudo chown avahi-autoipd:avahi-autoipd -R /var/lib/avahi-autoipd
sudo chown colord:colord -R /var/lib/colord
```

reboot

These commands did the trick for me.

Comment: Anyone, reading this, have messed up with /var permission, should try this.

Answer (score 10):

- **If you have a problem with the restricted (closed source) driver** , then try to remove it.

Open a terminal and give this command

```
gksudo software-properties-gtk
```

Goto **Additional drivers** and remove the dirver. You have to mark the **Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau**.

Then Reboot.

[image]

- If you have not access at all to the Desktop Environment then use the Recovery Mode.

To remove the **Nvidia current driver in Ubuntu 12.10**

[image]

[image]

Select the Network and your root partition will mounted as Read-Write.

[image]

Select the Root 
[image]

And then give these commands with order

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia-current 
rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf 
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
reboot
```

The last command will reboot your system and hopefully you will login normally in next reboot with the Open Source nouveau driver.

- **If you have problem with the open source driver (nouveau)** , in the same manner (from recovery mode) try to install the restricted (Nvidia) driver with these commands

When you reach the Root selection and after select root

**To install nvidia-current driver.**

```
 apt-get install linux-source 
 apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 apt-get install nvidia-current 
 nvidia-xconfig 
 reboot
```

#### According to this answer : [Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop does not show when I installed nvidia drivers!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/ubuntu-12-10-desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers) may need to install or reinstall the linux-headers to get the restricted Nvidia drivers work properly.

Comment: This is not a problem with the restricted or closed driver. It came just after i had a fresh install of 12.10 on my laptop.

Comment: Then try to do the opposite . Follow the guide from recovery mode and install the restricted driver , when you reach the root environment give these commands `apt-get install nvidia-current` and `nvidia-xconfig` and `reboot` I edited my answer.

Comment: Didn't work on my laptop :(

Comment: You are a legend, man. This solved my problems. It astounds me that after TWELVE years they still haven't included a solid default multi-monitor installation for one of the TWO most common graphics card types in the world.

Answer (score 7):

This problem destroyed my morning.  It turns out that if your root filesystem runs out of space then Ubuntu will boot into low graphics mode and it's hard to figure out why since the xorg log shows nothing wrong.  To find out from the command line if you're low on space type

```
df -h
```

Sample output from my machine:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        18G   10G  6.6G  61% /
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G  108K  3.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           1.6G  1.2M  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G  1.3M  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   16K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda4       317G   33G  285G  11% /media/data
/dev/sda1       197M   16M  182M   8% /boot/efi
```

If your `/` mount has a high `Use%` (90%+) then this could be your problem.  In my case, `~/.xsession.errors` had grown to fill most of my partition and caused me to fall into low-graphics mode.  Found my answer for that in this [Ubuntuforums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1517991):

```
rm ~/.xsession-errors
mkdir ~/.xsession-errors
```

Answer (score 6):

Try delete your /etc/X11/xorg.conf and restart.

Before restart, run

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem.

When I was booting my PC, i was getting the following message:
“Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode”

When I used `startx` on the command prompt however, everything was
fine and i could start the xserver.

Now I found out that for some strange reason GDM has been uninstalled 
(it took me hours to realize that), i did fix the problem by reinstalling gdm with:

```
apt-get install gdm
```

now everything's running. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I had the same problem and solved it.

1. Start ubuntu with **recovery mode** from grub then choose **filesystem check** followed by **enable networking**.
2. Choose root option to get to terminal. Now uninstall the old drivers

   `sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall`
3. Then reinstall the drivers following the methods for precise from this website https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI.
4. After that everything works out just fine, I suggest you do

   `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get autoremove`

   -everytime you complete a step. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Install gdm from the default Ubuntu repositories. OIn 16.04 and later gdm has been updated to gdm3. GDM provides the equivalent of a "login:" prompt for X displays: it asks for a login and starts X sessions.

During the installation of gdm you will be asked to select either gdm (or gdm3 in 16.04 and later) or lightdm as the default login display manager. Select gdm.

---

#### NVIDIA graphics

*nvidia-current* has been discontinued in Ubuntu 18.04 and later in favor of the proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver that is shown by `ubuntu-drivers devices` and installed by `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`. The name of the Nvidia driver package starts with *nvidia-driver-*. Search for all available Nvidia driver packages with `apt search nvidia-driver-*`

#### AMD graphics

*fglrx* has been discontinued in Ubuntu 16.04 and later in favor of the built-in AMD graphics driver.

Answer (score 4):

You said that you were stuck in low graphics mode and now you say that you can only get a command prompt. What happens when you type: `startx`

If you are stuck in a command prompt all is not lost. You can still reconfigure xserver with: `sudo dpkg --reconfigure --phigh xserver-xorg`

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure xorg no longer does anything useful, since X is generally much better at detecting your hardware than our crufty old maintainer scripts were.

Comment: not allays true @RAOF, I have some old hardware that can not be properly detected unless I reinstall xorg completely.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with an Acer Aspire 3810tg. I solved it by doing the following:

- Do a normal boot
- Press Ctrl-Alt-F1 on the "Your system is running in low-graphics mode" screen
- Download the correct driver from http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx, in my case (ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4330): `wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run` which should also cover your case (Mobility Radeon HD 4xxx Series)
- `chmod 755 amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run` to make the file executable
- `sudo ./amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run` and follow the standard steps
- You might need to run: `sudo aticonfig --initial`, but that was not necessary for me.

In my case the driver installation finished with an error, but it still worked. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Which ubuntu version are you running? Did you installed graphics drivers before the problem or is it a post clean-os-install issue? Giving some more info would be helpful for us to help you.

If you messed with the graphic drivers before the problem came up, get to the login screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login, then:

- `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo apt-get linux-source linux-headers-generic`
- `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`
- `sudo nvidia-xconfig`
- `sudo shutdown -r now`

Of course, if you have an ATI videocard you have to change the `nvidia-*` and `nvidia-current` for your ATI drivers package.

Comment: What are you expecting to do with `sudo apt-get linux-source linux-headers-generic`, apt-get will return error.

Comment: similar to this answer, and after trying several other answers:

`dpkg -l | grep nvidia`

then remove purge every single package from this list, e.g.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia`

finally,

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`
`sudo shutdown -r now`

Answer (score 3):

**Phenomenon**: I first saw `Booting without full network configuration` message that never ended. After Action-1 below, I faced `The system is running in low-graphics mode` issue.

**Action-1**: Force to shutdown the machine (by keeping power button pressed as normal). Choose recovery boot.

**Effective solution**: Remove & install `xserver-xorg`, inspired by [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/167005/24203).

---

Edit) after creating xorg.conf and had it read in xserver, I faced the same issue again. This time, in addition to re-install `xserver-xorg`, I had to create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file (I did so by copying the backup file I already made).

Comment: @guntbert agreed. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to disable `Internal Graphics Board` on BIOS display.

Using `ga-z87n/ga-h87n (GIGABYTE)` motherboard.

Answer (score 3):

Or, the most likely of the reasons with old PC's is:

#### Your graphic card just do not support unity.

Try Lubuntu/Xubuntu instead.

Unity requires: Any graphics card with OpenGL 1.4 support (All GPUs released today by either NVidia, AMD or Intel; GPUs released by NVidia and AMD over the last 5 years; GPUs released by Intel after the GMA 950). If you card don't meet this requirements, then is just that you can't use Unity (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot from grub using a different parameter or even booting an older kernel from the list.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

See the section on kernel options. Something like: xforcevesa

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm
sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xgl compiz compiz-plugins compiz-core compiz-manager csm cgwd cgwd-themes
sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz compiz-core compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-gnome compiz-plugins libcompizconfig0
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
```

choose the driver 'ati' and when you get to monitor resolution choose the resolution you want to run and any resolution ABOVE that resolution should be removed. Once that is done issue the following:*

```
sudo reboot
```

You will most likely get errors on specific packages.  Repeat the command removing the problem package until it works.

There will be a time where you will be without the desktop, so have another internet connected device nearby to reference this from or to Google with in case of emergency.

This worked for me, hope this helps.

*If you are never prompted, just skip this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a terminal
2. log in
3. look at the end of your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`
4. if the message error is **Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs.** then run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
   sudo reboot
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but this method works for me.

When you get  `The system is running low-graphics mode` error,press `ctrl+alt+F1` ,it will take you to the console.
Then it will asks for `username` and `password`to login,give that.Once you logged in to the console run the below command,

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo service lightdm restart
```

It will get you back to the GUI login.Why this problem occurs means,after you installed `graphics drivers`,it creates `xorg.conf` file in `/etc/X11` folder.Which prevents the system from `GUI login`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a special case of this problem, where I somehow caused the removal of some packages. I only noticed the actual problem after some time spent looking at the problem.

So:

1. Log into the text mode console
2. Enter the command: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

This will ensure all the needed packages are installed. Without some of those, symptoms like those described here may occur.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Memory may be bad.**

If you experience Low graphics mode intermittently like I was.

1. Run a memory check to check for memory errors.
2. Buy New memory(Make sure it is the right type for your computer)
3. Run the memory test again, to make sure all is good.

The Low Graphics Mode error should now be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue when I upgraded from 11.10 on my Acer Aspire One AO-722. I also had the propriety ATi/AMD driver installed from 11.10, which carried over to the 12.04 installation. I followed this guide to remove the proprietary drivers and use the Open Source drivers. http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx
Everything seems to be working now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the kernel headers manually then reinstall nvidia for some reason then the nvidia drivers will work

Comment: The modules for the driver have to be build for the individual kernel to use and this is why the kernel headers have to be installed. Usually they are pulled in via dependencies when installing the drivers.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I installed the headers and then the drivers as mentioned :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba Portege R100. I got this error after the first bootup after install. After downloading and updating the graphics driver (Trident Cyberblade), what worked for me was creating a driver-specific .conf file as described in this Arch-Linux wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Trident.

Comment: Wanted to add that, clearly, this is an Arch Linux link, not an Ubuntu link, but the solution worked for me. Now, however, I'm digging into it further, in terms of turning different options on and off, and I realize it works very differently from the way described in the comments. So keep this in mind if you try this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by creating a new xorg.conf file (copying the text from xorg.conf.failsafe).

Details:
https://askubuntu.com/a/296217/55223

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by removing `/var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority` manually.

You can also try deleting the file `~/.Xauthority` and rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error after trying to upgrade my Acer Aspire 4810T with Intel GM45 Express Chipset graphics from a 64bit 13.04 to a 64bit 13.10.

I had less than 2 gigabytes of free disk space when I started the upgrade. I faced first anomalies already before the reboot. The upgrade window showing the progress showed that everything has been downloaded and installed but it never closed. Couldn't close it even manually.

Then, after reboot, I got the “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error window.

I tried to solve the problem as proposed above by Luis Alvarado, user41938,  community wiki, Azul Mascara and David M. Sousa.

My guess is that my problem was related to tiny disk space as hinted by Azul Mascara. But just freeing disk space and even allocating more by repartitioning didn't help.

After struggling more than enough with the problem I decided to download the 13.10 64bit and make a bootable USB stick with it. I booted the laptop with the USB stick and selected the installation on top of the old 13.10 (non-functioning) system that the installer recognized. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, type the following commands:

```
$ lspci | grep -i VGA
$ lspci | grep -i amd
```

For me (HP pavilion 15n003tx, Saucy), the outputs were:

```
test@HP-Pavilion-15:/etc/X11$ lspci | grep -i VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
test@HP-Pavilion-15:/etc/X11$ lspci | grep -i amd
0a:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M]
```

Since the AMD device doesn't come as output in the first command, even if you install amd drivers, you'll probably end up with the following error in /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[    12.873] (II) fglrx(0): Invalid ATI BIOS from int10, the adapter is not VGA-enabled
```

Hence, I followed the steps:

```
test@HP-Pavilion-15:/etc/X11$ sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
test@HP-Pavilion-15:/etc/X11$ cp /etc/Xorg/xorg.conf.failsafe /etc/xorg.conf
```

The contents of xorg.conf.failsafe are:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "fbdev"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me using ubuntu 13.10, my ubuntu stopped working after installing `opencv`.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-304 nvidia-current nvidia-libopencl1-304 nvidia-settings
```

Just purge all the nvidia-* and restart

I am not a geek just a layman don't know the reason why it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (The system is running in low-graphics mode) when I reboot the system connected to an Oculus Rift (1080x1920 monitor). If I reboot the machine and connect a monitor of (1920x1080 resolution) it works ok.

The machine has Ubuntu 14.04 and Nvidia 970, driver 346 and kernel 3.15. With the default lightdm configuration (autologin activated).

The problem started suddenly, without making major changes in Ubuntu configuration.

I had the same issue in another machine with nvidia 970, same version of Ubuntu / different kernel. On this machine the problem happened when changing from autologin to login with user/pw in lightm and it was solved rebooting the machine with a 1920x1080 monitor connected and enabling autologin again.

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem occurred after upgrading from "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" plus TDE to "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" plus TDE. TDE is the trinity desktop environment (trinitydesktop.org). The cause of the error was that

1. `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` pointed to `lightdm` although during the upgrade I told it to use `tdm-trinity` as default.
2. lightdm was broken (and I don't care why).

The fix was to run `dpkg-reconfigure tdm-trinity` and to choose `tdm-trinity` as my default.
A few days later the problem came back and again `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` pointed to lightdm, don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Different users solved their in different ways (since the causes of the problem were different for different people). I am describing what caused the problem in my desktop and how did I solve it.

WARNING: My method will work on your computer only if the cause of the problem is the same. Nevertheless read my reply to develop a general understanding.

Cause of the problem:

I made some changes to the file

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

After I rebooted I encountered the 'system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode' error. Clearly the changes made to the above 'lightdm.conf' file needed to be undone.

How did I solve it:

1. When the error message appears, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, then login using your ubuntu username and password.
2. Go to the directory /etc/lightdm/ (cd /etc/lightdm/). Open the above file in vim using `vim lightdm.conf`. Vim opens the file in the terminal itself.
3. Undo the changes that caused the problem. In my case I removed a line that I had added (which caused the problem). Save and quit vim. Following this step requires you to know how to use vim editor to edit files. If you are unfamiliar with vim watch tutorials on how to open a file, edit a file, save and quit a file in vim.
4. Reboot the computer. The problem is gone!

PS: I undid the change that caused the error. Your cause of error could be completely different from mine. So, blindly following my answer definitely won't help. On the other hand it may damage your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after upgrading from 14.04 to 15.10 (and then to 16.04). For some reason the `/var/lib/lightdm` directory was missing.

To fix the issue, first, create the directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/lightdm
sudo chown -R lightdm:lightdm /var/lib/lightdm
sudo chmod 0750 /var/lib/lightdm
```

Then create the `.Xauthority` file:

```
sudo touch /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority
sudo chown lightdm:lightdm /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority
```

More details:

Most of the solutions revolve around ATI or NVidia drivers, but I just have an Intel integrated graphics chip, so that wasn't the issue.

I discovered the actual problem by looking at the greeter log:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
Error writing X authority: Failed to open X authority /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority: No such file or directory
```

Indeed, the `/var/lib/lightdm` was absent. Just creating the empty directory (as recommended in [another question's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/692627/344674)) resulted in the same error, but after creating the `.Xauthority` file, the system booted fine

Edit: Just found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720321/15-10-lightdm-broken-gdm-works) that has two answers: [one recommending creating the directory](https://askubuntu.com/a/738251/344674), [the other recommending creating the file](https://askubuntu.com/a/721027/344674). As I said, I needed to do both.

Answer (score 0):

**I face this error almost 100 times.**

```
  **1.Go to tty mode (ctrl + alt + F1)**

   2. Login with the existing user credentials.
   3. Run the single command **(  sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade )**
   4. Reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing this error after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10.

From a text console, I changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` to `"nosplash nomodeset"` so I could see the boot messages and ran `sudo update-grub`.

Upon reboot I saw that it was the "GNOME display manager" that had failed. Hey, wasn't I using LightDM? After running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to switch back from GDM3 to LightDM, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a 16.04 box with Intel integrated graphics this morning and found my way here. What worked for me:

When presented with the low-graphics-mode message at boot and unable to click "OK", I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up the terminal (in glorious full-screen text mode), and logged in.

I was going to follow the steps to reinstall the whole desktop, but then I noticed there were updates available. `sudo apt update` revealed that kernel updates were among them, and `sudo apt upgrade` installed the updates. Then `sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot.

And the problem went away. Probably some kind of bug with a previous version of the kernel. The recent change that I made that may have brought this on was installing a larger VGA monitor with a native resolution of 1680 x 1050. Anyway, everything seems to be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me is to switch lightdm to gdm:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3

systemctl stop lightdm
systemctl start gdm3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reconfigure your display manager**

Run

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm`

replacing `sddm` with you display manager (https://wiki.debian.org/DisplayManager), and choose one from the list that will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

**Yet another cause -- memory upgrade!**

I have system with both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 installed.  Both 64-bit, of course.  It had been working just fine (well fine-ish) with only 8 GB of RAM installed.  I decided to upgrade it to 32 GB (the max supported by the motherboard).  After installing the new RAM, of course I booted memtest86 and tested the new memory very thoroughly: no errors after more than 24 hours of running the test.  I booted Windows and it showed 32 GB of memory and had no issues.  I booted into Ubuntu and got the "system is running in low graphics mode".

**Nothing** had changed except for the additional memory!

Any number of articles on the web -- here at askubuntu and elsewhere -- claim that if you have 64-bit kernels, no settings changes should be necessary when you upgrade memory; it should just work.

It was **not** a problem of having too-small a swap partition for the larger memory.  That was one of the first things I checked.  When the OS was installed a 90 GB swap partition had been created, which is more than enough.

After wasting about a day checking various things, what finally worked for me was to:

- reboot into recovery mode
- rerun the "mkswap" utility to re-initialize the swap partition.
- reboot

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq for details on how much swap space is needed and how to use the mkswap utility.

I can only *guess* that when it saw the expanded memory, the kernel decided that the page size of the swap file should have a new value, and that did not match whatever whatever the page size was when the swp partition was initialized.  So then virtual memory failed to enable, and somehow that led to a cascade of failures.